# Fitting Constructor for a Custom adapter

Tags: java, android, constructor, adapter, android-adapter

I am trying to create a custom adapter, I have an error saying there is no default constructor available

```
public class GuessAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Game> {

    Context context;
    int resource;
    Peg[] guess;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public void PegArrayAdapter(Peg[] array, Context ctxt){
        guess= array;
        context = ctxt;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return guess.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Game getItem(int arg0){
        return guess[arg0];
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0){
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2){

        View view = arg1;

        if (arg1==null){
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arg2, false);
        }

        ImageView imageView =(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView imageView2=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView imageView3=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView imageView4=(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        return view;
    }
}
```

what would the fitting constructor for this adapter be?

Answer (score 0):

this

```
public void GuessAdapter(Peg[] array, Context ctxt){
     super(ctxt, 0, array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any constructor to your custom adapter. You need to make a constructor which would call `super`.

Add this method in your custom adapter

```
public GuessAdapter(Peg[] array, Context ctxt) {
    super(ctxt, 0, array);
    guess= array;
    context = ctxt;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Also, there is no use of method `PegArrayAdapter`, you can remove this afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way of making custom Adapter is to use BASEADAPTER.
There will be no issue in that.
Just extend your CustomAdapter class to BaseAdapter.
I hope it works fine.